# Extracting features from multiple curves

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, feature-extraction

I am building a model that predicts the SOH of a lithium ion battery.
My data are from 600 battery charge cycles as follows: for each cycle I have 3 curves each of length 128 samples: voltage, current and derivative of voltage. Also I have the real SOH for each cycle. My question is how I can encode these 3x600 curves to a feature space of around 5-6 features per cycle, that I will then feed to a LSTM model. The LSTM will take the features of the 10 previous cycles and will predict the SOH of the next 3. Thanks in advance.